# First order dynamics of tyre parameters identification

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, control-engineering, system-identification

I am looking for methods to determine relaxation length (or time constant) of a tyre for a bicycle model vehicle.
the equation describing the dynamics of tyre force is a given as follows:

tau.dFij/dt = -Fij+Fij_ss

With  Fij : is the tyre force i={x,y}(Longitudinal,Lateral) ,  j ={f,r} (Front,Rear}.

tau(what I am looking for) : is the time constant of the model which includes relaxation length.

tau  = relaxation_length/(velocity of the vehicle)

Fij_ss : steady state tyre force that I determined using empirical model (dugoff's model).

I did identify the coefficients of dugoff model to a set of input-output data from carsim software.

If someone has already worked on this, can please guide me into a method to compute the relaxation length.

Comment: Generally it is of the order of the radius of the tire. Computing it for a given tire is not something I have seen done, I imagine the usual approach is to test a tire. I suspect the FEA models created by the manufacturers would show this effect, but for us mere mortals we rely on tests.